# regexp and escaped char in scheme

Tags: regex, scheme, escaping, split, racket

in scheme,

there is `"hello hellu-#\"hella.helloo,hallo#\return#\""` string

I want to list them as ("hello" "hellu" "hella" "helloo" "hallo")

separate by space, hyphen, double quote, dot, comma, return

I tried

```
(regexp-split #rx"( +)|(#\-)|(#\")|(#\.)|(,)|(#\return)" string)
```

but `#\- , #\.` make error

any hint or solution?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the syntax for characters (`#\foo`) with the syntax for strings, and you do that in both the string and the regexp.  So my guess is that the string that you want to split is actually:

```
"hello hellu-\"hella.helloo,hallo\n\""
```

where `\"` stands for a double quote character, and `\n` for a newline.  If this is the case, then (again, this is guessing your intention) the regexp should be:

```
(regexp-split #rx"( +)|(\-)|(\")|(\.)|(,)|(\n)" string)
```

But that doesn't work either, since `\-` and `\.` are invalid escapes (Racket uses C-like escapes), so change that to:

```
(regexp-split #rx"( +)|(-)|(\")|(.)|(,)|(\n)" string)
```

This doesn't work either, since `.` has the usual "any char" meaning in a regexp -- so you want to escape it with a backslash.  As with many other string syntaxes, you get a backslash by escaping it with a backslash, so now we have a version that is finally close to a working one:

```
> (define string "hello hellu-\"hella.helloo,hallo\n\"")
> (regexp-split #rx"( +)|(-)|(\")|(\\.)|(,)|(\n)" string)
'("hello" "hellu" "" "hella" "helloo" "hallo" "" "")
```

First, the regexp can be improved considerably: the parens are not needed for splitting:

```
(regexp-split #rx" +|-|\"|\\.|,|\n" string)
```

Then, instead of using a bunch of single-characters with `|`s, you can just use a "character range":

```
(regexp-split #rx" +|[-\".,\n]" string)
```

Note that it's important that the `-` is the first (or last) character in the range, so it will not have the usual meaning of a range of characters.  Next, it seems that you really want any sequence of such characters to be used as a separator, which will avoid some of those empty strings in the result:

```
(regexp-split #rx" +|[-\".,\n]+" string)
```

and in this case you can just as well throw the space into the range too (carefully putting it *after* the `-`, as I explained above).  We now get:

```
> (define string "hello hellu-\"hella.helloo,hallo\n\"")
> (regexp-split #rx"[- \".,\n]+" string)
'("hello" "hellu" "hella" "helloo" "hallo" "")
```

And finally you'd probably want to get rid of that last empty string.  Technically, it *should* be there, since there is a sequence of matching characters before the end of the string.  An easy way in Racket around this is to use the complementary `regexp-match*` which returns the list of *matches* rather than splitting on the list of matches:

```
> (define string "hello hellu-\"hella.helloo,hallo\n\"")
> (regexp-match* #rx"[- \".,\n]+" string)
'(" " "-\"" "." "," "\n\"")
```

This is obviously broken, since it gives you the separators rather than what's between them.  But since this regexp is a range of characters, it is easy to resolve -- simply negate the character range, and you get what you want:

```
> (define string "hello hellu-\"hella.helloo,hallo\n\"")
> (regexp-match* #rx"[^- \".,\n]+" string)
'("hello" "hellu" "hella" "helloo" "hallo")
```